# Assign roles/recipes through client.rb in chef

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

My Client.rb file looking like mention below

```
On Node
cat client.rb 
log_level        :info
log_location     STDOUT
chef_server_url  "https://chef.my.com:443"
validation_client_name "mychef-validator"
environment "Rd-Staging"
```

and environment "Rd-Staging" have mention below information.

On Chef-workstation:

```
knife environment show Rd-Staging
chef_type:           environment
cookbook_versions:
  apache-yum:         = 0.1.0
default_attributes:
description:         Rd-Staging
json_class:          Chef::Environment
name:                Rd-Staging
override_attributes:
```

After that whenever I am hitting chef-client form node. Node is not compiling any cookbook while I am hitting the same chef-client from Chef-workstation its compiling same cookbook on same node.

Any how is that possible to assign recipes/roles through client.rb. I am trying to achieve whenever node come up it will enroll under particular environment then run environment dedicated recipes. Please keep that in mind i can not change first-boot.json because at that time in need to create multiple first-boot.json for different projects.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign the run list through the `client.rb` config file. In general you shouldn't set the environment that way either, it is there mostly for chef-solo. The run list and environment data lives in the Node object on the Chef Server. You can edit this data via `knife node edit` or via the Chef Server web interface.

More generally, environments can't have run list data attached to them, only roles and nodes get that.